# Tower of Hanoi in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm a newbie in php and I'm on the stage where I get every piece of php code and try to understand how it works. I started with some simple algorithms that I found on Wikipedia.

For Tower of Hanoi I have:

```
$i = 1;
function hanoi($plates, $from, $to) {
    global $i;
    while($plates > 0) {
        $i++;
        /* ????? */ $using = 6 - ($from + $to);  
        hanoi(--$plates, $from, $using);
        print "Move plate from $from to $to; ";
        $from = $using;
     }
}

//Arguments: No of plates, From stick(1, 2 or 3),
//To stick(1,2 or 3; except From stick)
hanoi(6, 1, 3);
print " Number of moves: $i";
```

Where is that 6 coming from?

Answer (score 0):

6 is the number of individual plates you are moving, but I think it may be hard-coded into the function for the sake of ease. Typically Hanoi has 6 plates.

EDIT: Just as a note, although its a good idea to look at PHP code that's already been done, Writing it yourself, even if you are copying it across, will give you a lot more experience in terms of learning the syntax faster in addition to understanding it better

Comment: That could be an explanation but I'm not sure that is the right one. Replacing the `6` with the number of plates will work just when the number of plates is greater or equal with 6. If we let `6` there will work with every number.  Thank you for the tips.